# addEventListener for type=button only works once

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm working on an assignment, where the user can draw inside an n*n grid. The tasks are as following:

- Create a 16x16 grid as default grid upon page-load
- Implement a mouseover-EventListener for the grid, that changes the background-color of cells to black
- Add a reset button, that asks the user how big the new grid should be
- Add 2 buttons that set the mouseover-EventListener (default black) to a different color. First button changes the color to yellow, second button to gray.

**My problem:**
I'm stuck with the last task. The 2 buttons work just fine. But they can be called only once. If I select yellow - it draws yellow. If I then select gray - it draws gray. After that, the button-clicks don't do anything anymore, but I can still draw in gray.

**That's what I have done so far:**
First, I querySelected the button-type and added an EventListener "click".

Second, in the colourHover function, a mouseover EventListener gets invoked, depending on the button's id.

Third, the EventListener-mouseover gets defined in the respective functions (`grayColour(event)`, `yellowColour(event)`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="start">
<div class="container" id="grid">
</div>
<div><button type="button" class="button" id="gray">Gray Colour</button></div>
<div><button type="button" class="button" id="yellow">Yellow Colour</button></div>
<div><button type="button" id="button">Resize your grid manually.</button></div>

<script>
"use strict";

let container = document.getElementById("grid");
let n;

// creating a grid with number-input from user.
let makeGrid = function makeGrid(input) {
    let c;
    
    for (c = 0; c < (input * input); c++) {
        let cell = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(cell).className = "squares";
        
    };
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${input}, auto)`;
    container.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${input}, auto)`;
};

// function gets exectuted, only if a number and below 101
let numberCheck = function numberCheck() {
    
    if ((n % n) === 0 && n <= 100) {
    makeGrid(n);
};

    while ((n % n) !== 0) {
        alert("Please enter a number.");
        n = prompt("Choose again.");
        if ((n % n) === 0 && n <= 100) {
            makeGrid(n);
        }
    };

    while ((n % n) === 0 && n > 100) {
        alert("The number is too high.");
        n = prompt("Choose again.");
        if ((n % n) === 0 && n <= 100) {
            makeGrid(n);
        }
        else if ((n % n) !== 0) {
            alert("Please enter a number");
            n = prompt("Choose again");
                if ((n % n) === 0 && n <= 100) {
                    makeGrid(n);
                }
        }
    };
    
};

// default grid on first pageload
makeGrid(16);

// this function sets the hovered items colour to black on default / first pageload
let blackColor = function blackColor(event) {
    let colour = event.target;
    if (colour.className === "container") {
        return;
    }
    else if (colour.className === "squares") {
        colour.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    };
};

// addEventListener for blackColor function
let hoverItems = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
    hoverItems.forEach(element => { element.addEventListener("mouseover", blackColor)
});



// function to manual selecting a grid-size. Beforehand, old grid gets deleted
let removeElements = function removeElements(event) {
    let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("squares");
    while (elements.length > 0) {
        elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0]);
    };
    n = prompt("Choose the size of your grid");
    numberCheck(n);
};

// button for selecting a grid-size manually
let button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("click", removeElements);


// this function sets the background-color of the cells on mouseover to gray
let grayColour = function grayColour(event) {
        let colour = event.target;
        if (colour.className === "container") {
        return;
    }
    else if (colour.className === "squares") {
        colour.style.backgroundColor = "gray"

    }
}
// this function sets the background-color of the cells on mouseover to yellow
let yellowColour = function yellowColour(event) {
    let colour = event.target;
    if (colour.className === "container") {
        return;
    }
    else if (colour.className === "squares") {
    colour.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

}
}


let colourHover = function colourHover(event) {
    let hover = document.querySelectorAll(".container");
    switch (event.target.id) {
        case "gray":
            //hover.forEach(element => { element.removeEventListener("mouseover", yellowColour)
            //});
            //hover.forEach(element => { element.removeEventListener("mouseover", grayColour)
            //});
            hover.forEach(element => { element.addEventListener("mouseover", grayColour)
        });
        break;
        case "yellow":
        //hover.forEach(element => { element.removeEventListener("mouseover", yellowColour)
            //});
            //hover.forEach(element => { element.removeEventListener("mouseover", grayColour)
            //});
        hover.forEach(element => { element.addEventListener("mouseover", yellowColour)
        });
        break;
};
};

let colourBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
colourBtn.forEach(element => { element.addEventListener("click", colourHover)
});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate any hint in the right direction. Really stuck right now.

Comment: The events are actually working, but you're adding new `mouseover` events every time you click on a button. That way all those events are doing their job, but you see only the result of the last executed event. This would be easier to handle by attaching a mouseover to the parent element of the grid, and control only the color by the buttons. In the delegated mouseover you can check the target to restyle, and read the correct color from in an outer scope declared variable you'll manage with the buttons.

Comment: All things aside I just want to say this is some nice looking code. Good variable names and formatting. Really good job so far! Keep it up @Mohemi

Comment: Your snippet seems to depend on some HTML + CSS that's not included. Whatever, setting breakpoints or console.log() statements in your event handlers should illustrate what Teemu says.

Comment: I agree with Teemu (and Danoram!) but to get this working you simply need to remove all event listeners from your elements in the `hover.forEach()` calls before adding your new ones. `element.removeEventListener("mouseover", yellowColour); element.removeEventListener("mouseover", grayColour);`

Comment: SOLVED! Thanks Teemu.
For future readers I just wanted to add, that pilchards suggestion also worked here. 

Furthermore, I updated the code-snippet according to Álvaro González 's suggestion after the initial release of this post. Hence, pilchards solution is in there as a comment. 

I'm a beginner, so i can only assume that Teemu 's elaborated answer is more scalable and the method to go for in general.  Thanks @Danoram and pilchard for the kind words. Meant a lot to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use CSS classes for styling the cells, and change the class of the table body in a button click handler. The state of the "widget" should be stored in a JS variable, that way you can avoid unnecessary DOM traversing on each click of the buttons. Something like this:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
    table = document.querySelector('.hovered-colors');
// The state of the widget
let currentColor = 'black';

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const newColor = e.target.getAttribute('data-color');
    table.classList.remove(currentColor);
    table.classList.add(newColor);
    currentColor = newColor;
  });
});
```

```css
.black td:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.gray td:hover {
  color: black;  
  background-color: gray;
}

.yellow td:hover {
  color: black;  
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody class="hovered-colors black">
    <tr><td>R1C1</td><td>R1C2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R2C1</td><td>R2C2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>R3C1</td><td>R3C2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button data-color="gray">Gray</button>
<button data-color="yellow">Yellow</button>
```